# Adding emphasis (italics) to a word in a chapter title LyX

Tags: lyx, emphasis

I have a chapter title which contains a word which needs to be in italics. LyX allows me to add emphasis to it in the LyX window (with Ctrl+E) and it appears italicized in the LyX window. However, in both the table of contents and the chapter itself the word is not in italics. This seems odd because figure and table labels do appear in their respective lists with proper emphasis. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `ctrl+i`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which document class are you using? Have you done any customization of how chapters are printed?

Comment: Sigur, I tried that and it has no effect.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem, since `\emph` (using Ctrl + E) shows clearly in the chapter title and ToC (under the `report` standard class).

Comment: @Werner I assume (s)he is using a KOMA class, where chapters are set in bold, sans-serif, and there is no italic, bold ,sans-serif (in the default font at least). But I'd to have it confirmed.

Comment: Torbjorn T. I am using a class/template from here: https://cpbl.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/ubc-thesis-under-lyx-manuscript-based-thesis-under-latex/  I am a bit of a latex/lyx newb but am fairly competent on a computer. If I can find a place to start....

Comment: Without any modifications? I downloaded `ubcthesislyx.zip` from that link, as well as `genthesis.cls` and `ubcthesis.cls` from http://faculty.washington.edu/mforbes/projects/ubcthesis/, placed everything in the same folder and opened `ubcsamplelyx.lyx`. Emphasis in chapter titles worked fine. Edit: By the way, write `@username` like I did with Werner above to notify me about your comment. There is tab-completion, so after writing `@Tor` or something you should be able to press Tab to complete my username.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you! you have reminded me of what is probably the source of the problem. I've added the following to the preable:`\renewcommand\chapterfont{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\chaptertitlefont{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\sectionfont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\titlefont{\Large \bfseries}
\renewcommand\subtitlefont{\large \bfseries}` which I guess is forcing this behaviour...

Comment: Nope, still works with that addition.

Comment: Okay, I've followed your lead and started from a fresh download of the ubcsamplelyx.lyx. I now see I changed some of the fonts as well. I understand some don't have italics. Will report once I have it figured.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is due to using an obsolete font package

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the font I had used "AE (Almost European)" was causing the issue. It must not have both bold and italic fonts.

Changing it to Default (or other fonts) fixed this problem.

Comment: Fonts provide specific features (**bold**, or *italic*, or slanted, or small caps, or combinations of these). For the chapter font to be **bold** and *italic*, you need a font the provides both. Can you provide a link to this "AE" font?

Comment: That makes sense. Its "Almost European". I dont know anything about it other than it was there in the drop down menu.